# Will Appstore reject application with web contents?

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store

I have to develop an application for iOS using phone gap in which first page will show some icons and each will lead to some web page contents, i want to know whether App Store has any restrictions on such kind of app. If can't what is the alternative way.

I have checked this [Guidelines](http://way2ios.com/development/ios-development-2/app-store-review-guidelines/) and i can't reach on a conclusion. 
If it is possible only i can start to develop my application. Kindly remember i'am a new bee to App Store. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can have web contents and there are lots of PhoneGap/Cordova-based Apps available.

The only requirement is to have an App that is more than a simple embedded web site. Add some native functionality, navigation/tab bars, native image picker, etc.

Comment: each of my icons will lead to webpages, is there any problem with that.There is nothing to do native.

Comment: You'll have some navigation controles and ways to reload the web contents. I think that would be enough "native code" to get accepted.